# Is there any alternative to the "sed -i" command in Solaris?

Tags: text-processing, sed, solaris

I have a requirement in my project to replace some existing text in a file like **`foo`** with some other text like **`fooofoo`**:

```
abc.txt
name
foo
foo1
```

So I tried:

```sh
sed -i "s/foo/fooofoo/g" abc.txt
```

However I get this error:

> sed: illegal option -- `i`

I found in the manual that I have to use:

```sh
sed -i\ "s/foo/fooofoo/g" abc.txt
```

However this is not working either.

I found alternatives in `perl` and `awk` also but a solution in Solaris `sed` would be much appreciated.

I am using this version of bash:

> GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.10)

Comment: On Solaris 11 and later, simply use `/usr/gnu/bin/sed` to get -i support.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`ed`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/ed-1.html#scrolltoc). It's available on most platforms and it can edit your files in-place.
Since `sed` is based on `ed` the syntax for replacing patterns is similar:

```
ed -s infile <<\IN
,s/old/new/g
w
q
IN
```

Comment: Why [`ed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html) instead of [`ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html), just curious?  (I know both are POSIX compliant and I've linked to the specs. ;) )

Comment: @Wildcard - I could ask the opposite - why `ex` ? To answer your question: since I never use `ex`  I'm not familiar with it. btw, I've seen setups where `ed` was present but `ex` was not (but not the opposite)... the most notable being my laptop :)

Comment: Good answer.  :)  My answer: Since I use Vim all the time, I am very familiar with `ex` commands.  All the `vi` commands you can type that start with a colon are `ex` commands.  There are of course a few Vim-specific extensions, but just the core set of commands is incredibly powerful and flexible and is plenty for scripted edits.

Comment: My Manjaro system has `ex` and yet not `ed`.

Answer (score 8):

If you cannot install GNU sed, use:

```
sed "s/foo/fooofoo/g" abc.txt >abc.tmp && mv abc.tmp abc.txt
```

This uses *redirection* to send the output of sed to a temporary file.  If sed completes successfully, then this overwrites `abc.txt` with the temporary file.

[As can be seen from the source code for GNU sed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27075334/3030305), this is exactly what `sed -i` does.  So, this is just about as efficient as `sed -i`.

If there is a chance that `abc.tmp` already exists, then you may want to use `mktemp` or a similar utility to generate the unique name for the temporary.

Comment: Thanks for help. However Is there any option in solaris by which we can update the existing file without creating a temp file?

Comment: Hate to break it to you, but even sed creates a temporary file. http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/tree/sed/sed.c#n84

Comment: You can do it if you don't care about hard links - see my example.  There's still a temporary file, but it's hidden (unnamed).  Without a temporary, you'd need to use `ed`, since it reads the whole file into memory.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the equivalent of `sed -i.bak`, it's pretty simple.

Consider this script for GNU sed:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Create an input file to demonstrate
trap 'rm -r "$dir"' EXIT
dir=$(mktemp -d)
grep -v '[[:upper:][:punct:]]' /usr/share/dict/words | head >"$dir/foo"

# sed program - removes 'aardvark' and 'aardvarks'
script='/aard/d'

##########
# What we want to do
sed -i.bak -e "$script" "$dir"
##########

# Prove that it worked
ls "$dir"
cat "$dir/foo"
```

We can simply replace the marked line with

```sh
cp "$dir/foo" "$dir/foo.bak" && sed -e "$script" "$dir/foo.bak" >"$dir/foo"
```

This moves the existing file to be a backup, and writes a new file.

If we want the equivalent of

```sh
sed -i -e "$script" "$dir"  # no backup
```

then it's slightly more complex.  We can open the file for reading as standard input, then unlink it, before directing sed's output to replace it:

```sh
( cp "$dir/foo" "$dir/foo.bak"; exec <"$dir/foo.bak"; rm "$dir/foo.bak"; exec sed -e "$script" >"$dir/foo" )
```

We do this in a sub-shell, so that our original stdin is still available after this.  It's possible to switch inputs and switch back without a subshell, but this way seems clearer to me.

Note that we're careful to copy first, rather than creating a new `foo` file - this is important if the file is known by more than one name (i.e. has hard links) and you want to be sure that you don't break the links.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should know that the `i\` command you're referring to is for *inserting a line of text*—not for saving the edited text back to the file.  There is no [POSIX-specified way](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) to use `sed` for that.

What you *can* do is use [`ex`, which *is* specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html):

```
printf '%s\n' '%s/find/replace/g' 'x' | ex file.txt
```

The `x` command is for "save and exit."  You can also use `wq` but `x` is shorter.

The `%` sign at the start of the substitute command means, "Apply this command to every line in the buffer."  You could use `1,$s/find/replace/g` also.

---

One major difference between `ex` and `sed` is that `sed` is a *stream* editor.  It only operates sequentially, line by line.  `ex` is far more flexible than that, and in fact you can do interactive text file editing directly in `ex`.  It is the immediate predecessor to `vi`.

Answer (score 2):

## Using `sed` and no *visible* temporary file:

You can avoid creating a separate *visible* "temp file":

```
exec 3<abc.txt
rm abc.txt
sed 's/foo/fooofoo/' <&3 >abc.txt
exec 3<&-
```

## Explanation

Unix-like systems don't actually remove the file's contents from the disk until it's *both* unlinked in the filesystem, *and* not open in any process. So you can do `exec 3<` to open the file in the shell for reading on file descriptor 3, `rm` the file (which unlinks it from the file system), and then call `sed` with file descriptor 3 used as its input.

Note that this is *very* different from this:

```
# Does not work.
sed 's/foo/fooofoo/' <abc.txt >abc.txt
```

The difference is that when you do it in one command, the shell just opens the same file for both reading, and for writing with the option to truncate the file - since it's still the same file, you lose the contents. But if you open it for reading, then `rm` it, then open the same pathname for writing, you're actually creating a new file at the same pathname (but at a new inode and disk location, since the original is still open): so the contents are still available.

Then once you're done, you can close the file descriptor you opened previously (that's what the `exec 3<&-` special syntax does), which releases the original file so the operating system can delete (mark as unused) its disk space.

## Caveats

There's a few things to keep in mind about this solution:.

1. You only get one "go" through the contents - there's no *portable* way for a shell to "seek" back in the file descriptor - so once a program reads some of the contents, other programs will only see the remainder of the file. And `sed` will read the entire file.
2. There's a small chance of your original file being lost if your shell/script/sed gets killed before it's done.

Comment: To be clear, @TobySpeight already posted an example of this solution at the end of his answer, but I thought it could use a more in-depth elaboration.

Comment: To the downvoter: While I'm sure just leaving a downvote makes you feel good about yourself, I'd appreciate if you'd contribute more by providing feedback as to what issues you have with this answer, how it can be improved, etc.

Comment: maybe you can use perl -i

Comment: @c4f4t0r: Sorry for the late reply: Yes, `perl -i` is another good option. The question specifically requested a solution compatible with Solaris' `sed`, in contrast to solutions with `perl` and `awk` that they mentioned already finding. Plus, my answer was mainly intended to add something that I thought was useful to know and missing from any of the other answers.