# Using sed command arguments to be compatible with both GNU & BSD Unix (in-place editing)

Tags: shell-script, sed, gnu, bsd

I have a shell script that I currently use for some build related stuff for a mobile application.

Due to the the subtle differences between BSD & GNU one of build scripts originally written on a Mac (BSD)

```
environment=$1

if [[ -z $environment ]]; then 
  environment="beta"
fi
if ! [[ $environment =~ (live|beta) ]]; then
  echo "Invalid environment: $environment"
  exit 1
fi

mobile_app_api_url="https://api"$environment".mysite.com"

cp app/index.html.mob MobileApp/www/index.html

sed -i'' "s#MOBILE_APP_API_URL#\"$mobile_app_api_url\"#g" MobileApp/www/index.html
```

The sed command has been written on BSD (Mac) but as builds may take place on both Mac or Ubuntu (GNU) I need to modify this to work with on both flavours, what is the best approach for this?

Comment: Use [`ed`, it can edit the files in-place](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/316349) and it's fully portable.

Comment: Use `perl -pi -e '...'`. Both BSD and GNU sed derived their `-i` from `perl`'s one. `perl` will be available on most GNU and BSD systems and most other systems.

Comment: `-i''` is actually `-i` (`-i` concatenated with the empty string) so would only work with GNU `sed`. You'd need `-i ''` for BSDs.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas There are Unices out there without Perl in the base system. NetBSD is one (but it may well be alone in that group).

Comment: @Kusalananda, true. In my experience, one is more likely to find `perl` than `bash` though. For instance here, many of the BSDs would not have `bash` or any shell that supports those `[[...]]` or `=~` (which can easily be replaced by a standard and more legible `sh` `case` construct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this to circumvent the problematic portability issues with the `-i` flag of `sed`:

```
sed 'sed-editing-commands' thefile >tmpfile && mv tmpfile thefile
```

I.e., write to a temporary file, and then replace the input file with the temporary file if the `sed` command didn't fail.

This is portable to all implementations of `sed` that I know of.

To create a temporary filename safely, use `mktemp`. Although this isn't a standard utility, it is available on all Unices that I have access to (OpenBSD, NetBSD, Solaris, macOS, Linux):

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
sed 'sed-editing-commands' thefile >"$tmpfile" && mv "$tmpfile" thefile
```

Comment: However, that doesn't make any attempt to preserve the ownership, permissions and other metadata of the original file like GNU or BSD seds would.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Good point. To do that, one would have to `cp thefile "$tmpfile"` first, I think. Does that sound about right?

Comment: Some good related reading in Scott's answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/117549

Answer (score 0):

You need to realize that the `$mobile_app_api_url` should not contain the chars
that are meaningful to sed on the RHS of s///. Specifically, speaking, you need
to make sure that this variable has the following properly escaped away: viz.,
    `& # \ newline` before they are plugged in.

Comment: It looks as if that is already taken care of. The URL will not cause problems. The issue is with the non-portable `-i` flag for `sed` (it work very differently with different implementations of `sed`).

Comment: From the OP's code shown there is nowhere any escaping the characters that I have mentioned above in my post. Just try placing an & in $1 to see what I mean.

Comment: The URL in `$mobile_app_api_url` will be either `https://apibeta.mysite.com` or `https://apilive.mysite.com`, no other values will be allowed. The escaping of characters in the substitution is furthermore an issue in all implementations of `sed` on all Unices. This question is about portability.

Comment: @Kusalananda, any value of `$environment` that **contains** either `live` or `beta` would be allowed (though it doesn't look like it was the intention).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Right you are. Any URL with `& # \ newline` in the domain part would be a bit broken anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
cp app/index.html.mob MobileApp/www/index.html
sed -i'' "s#MOBILE_APP_API_URL#\"$mobile_app_api_url\"#g" MobileApp/www/index.html
```

Just do:

```
sed "s#MOBILE_APP_API_URL#\"$mobile_app_api_url\"#g" \
  < app/index.html.mob >  MobileApp/www/index.html
```

You can also remove your dependency on `ksh93`/`bash` by changing the top part to:

```
environment=$1

case $environment in
  "") environment=beta;;
  live|beta) ;;
  *)
    printf >&2 'Invalid environment: "%s"\n' "$environment"
    exit 1;;
esac
```

See also `environment=${1:-beta}`.

BTW, `[[ $environment =~ (live|beta) ]]` in `ksh93` and `bash` tests whether `$environment` **contains** `live` or `beta` which doesn't sound like what you want. You'd need `[[ $environment =~ ^(live|beta)$ ]]` to test whether it **is** `live` or `beta`.